# How to stop a function which is still computing with button stop?

Tags: c++

I've an application visual c++ written using vs2010,
I have two buttons: "start" and "stop",the first one calls a function that takes a lot of time to process, so in a certain moment I'd like to stop the computation pressing stop button. But in my application the button start seems still clicked (I think it's waiting for the return of the function) and all the other buttons appear to be disabled. Even if I had a wonderful stop function, I could not active because I'm not able to click on button stop. Solutions,ideas,using threads,easy example? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to run your time-consuming function in an asynchronous way - e.g. by running it in a separate thread.

Comment: Windows, linux, osx? C++11 ? Boost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

BackgroundWorker is perfect for this use!

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your calculations in another thread. Otherwise your gui freezes until your calculations are done (because only one thing can be done at the moment).

If you are using some modern compiler look at std::thread.

other solutions are boost threads or even microsoft threads.

Answer (score 1):

If your computation is a loop, it may be quite easy to check at each iteration if your User wants to stop the computation.

In the computation thread:

```
while(compute){
    // one loop of computation
}
```

While your GUI thread can set `computation`to false through your `stop` button.
I hope it helps

Note: In c++ as in java Swing etc.., the GUI has it's own thread (not really visible to the developer) and you should never do heavy tasks in it. For instance, every callbacks for buttons should be as small as possible to keep your GUI responsive. This thread's job is just to drive your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button 1 -> onClick = 
{
    start thread -> { do stuff here }
}

BUtton 2 -> onClick = 
{
    close thread
}
```

Be careful when forcibly closing a thread because you can leak memory !

Comment: I had imagined such a solution, the problem is that with msdn or googling I can not find anything that works, since the syntax, the compiler does not want to recognize the threads!

Comment: What compiler and what flags are you using? You might also want to post some a code sample

Comment: I'm afraid the compiler that comes with VS 2010 does not support std::threads. You'll have to use boost threads or go for the MS specific solution

Comment: Now I know for certain! I'll have to start again from the msdn's mess!

Comment: Well, the alternative is to use a different compiler, e.g. gcc or clang with better support for c++11 features, or to use boost.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to imports the namespace

using System.Threading;

then use the following code :

```
Thread T=new Thread(Your Code Goes method name);


your method name()
{
// your code goes here
}
T.Start();

then 


T.Abort();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem terribly useful in its current form. I guess you're referring to the .NET Thread class? The OP has not mentioned using .NET yet. I generally wouldn't recommend to use `using namespace`, and aren't you missing a `*` in `Thread T=new Thread(...)`?